Rewriting a series of power-of-two Chebyshev polynomials with special functions or an integral (last step of Egorychev's method)
I would like to evaluate the contour integral,
\begin{eqnarray*}
I\left(x\right) &=& \lim\limits_{\rho \uparrow \infty} \int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} \frac{-4 \imath z\left(z^2 - 1\right) \ln 2  +\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(\imath z\right)\right)-\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(-\imath z\right)\right)}{8\pi z^{4}\ln2} e^{z \cos^{-1} x} dz
\end{eqnarray*} where $x \in \left[-1,1\right]$ and $\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a q-digamma function, which is the derivative of the logarithm of the q-gamma function and can be defined via a series
$$\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(y\right) = -\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n + y}}{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n + y}}.$$
I know that $I\left(x\right)$ is real, but even if it has no somewhat closed form, it might help if someone could manipulate it into the canonical form of an inverse Fourier transform or other integral transform.
How I Have Tried to Evaluate $I\left(x\right)$
I can use residues to evaluate the parts of the integral that do not involve $\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}$, namely
$$\lim\limits_{p \uparrow \infty} \int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} \frac{-4 \imath z\left(z^2 - 1\right) \ln 2}{8\pi z^{4}\ln2} e^{z \cos^{-1} x} dz = 1 - \frac{\left(\cos^{-1} x\right)^2}{2}$$
There are formulas for the residue of a simple pole or a higher order pole that I have been able to apply to the above integrand when $z = 0$ (so the value of $\rho$ is irrelevant) and multiply by $2\pi\imath$, which I can confirm in Mathematica 14 with either Residue or ContourIntegrate.
Those techniques are mostly insufficient for me to evaluate the parts of the integral that do involve $\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}$,
$$\lim\limits_{p \uparrow \infty} \int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} \frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(\imath z\right)\right)-\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(-\imath z\right)\right)}{8\pi z^{4}\ln2} e^{z \cos^{-1} x} dz$$
The numerator of the above integrand can be written as
$$\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(\imath z\right)\right)-\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(-\imath z\right)\right) = -\imath z \ln 2 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{2^{n + 1}}{4^n + z^2}$$
so there is a third-order pole at $z = 0$. Calculating the residue by differentiation and limits is tedious, but it does not depend on $\rho$, and I can do the steps somewhat manually. Residue in Mathematica confirms it is $-\frac{127 \imath\left(2048\cos^{-1}(x)^2-2359\right)}{2^{20}\pi}$.
As $\rho \uparrow \infty$, we also need to compute the residue at infinity. There are formulas for that, but I have not yet been able to evaluate the corresponding limits, and Residue in Mathematica does not return an answer either.
The integrand also has simple poles at $\mp \imath 2^k \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. When I apply the residue formula, each term in the infinite sum contributes one term to the residue (when $n = k$), which is
$$-\frac{\imath}{8\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left[\frac{2^{n + 1} e^{-\imath 2^n \cos^{-1} x}}{\left(-\imath 2^n\right)^3} + \frac{2^{n + 1} e^{\imath 2^n \cos^{-1} x}}{\left(\imath 2^n\right)^3}\right]$$
But I have not been able to determine what function of $x$ that series approaches.
Perhaps the integral over a circle of radius $\rho$ could be split into integrals over two near semi-circles where the nearly flat part of the semi-circle goes along the imaginary axis but slightly detours around the poles? But that sounds like something that is best left to professionals.
For a particular $x$, it works decently if I parameterize $z = \rho e^{\imath t}$, substitute $\imath e^{\imath t} dt$ for $dz$, and numerically integrate over $t$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$ for a "large finite" value of $\rho$. However, symbolic integration in Mathematica does not yield an answer for a generic $\rho$ if I parameterize the contour this way, and neither does it yield the limit of the reparameterized integrand as $\rho \uparrow \infty$. The Rubi interface to Mathematica seems to not have any rules for QPolyGamma, although its derivative is just a higher-order QPolyGamma function.
Motivation for Evaluating $I\left(x\right)$
My ultimate motivation for wanting to evaluate $I\left(x\right)$ is that
$$f(x) = \frac{3}{7} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 8^{-n} T_{2^n}\left(x\right) = I\left(x\right)$$
where $T_{2^n}\left(x\right) = \cos\left(2^n \cos^{-1} x\right)$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. The series representation is great numerically, but I am trying to obtain a better analytical understanding. The series defining $f$ converges because $\left|T_{2^n}\left(x\right)\right| \leq 1$ and $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 8^{-n} = \frac{4}{7}$. Also, I know the value of $f$ at Chebyshev-Lobatto (extrema) nodes such as $f\left(-1\right) = 0$, $f\left(0\right) = \frac{3}{8}$, $f\left(\frac{\mp 1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{27 \mp 16 \sqrt{2}}{64}$, and $f\left(1\right) = 1$, which could be used to spot-check an answer. In general, if $x$ is rational, then $f\left(x\right)$ is also rational, due to the facts that $T_{2^n}\left(x\right) = 2T_{2^{n - 1}}\left(x\right)^2 - 1$ and $T_{2^0}\left(x\right) = x$. This makes me a little bit more optimistic that $I\left(x\right)$ has some closed form, but it seems hard to see how $I\left(x\right)$ comes out rational when $x$ is rational.
Below I derive the above integral representation of $f$ using Egorychev's method, which has been used by Marko Riedel almost a hundred times on MSE alone. I believe Egorychev's method has never been applied to Chebyshev series, so perhaps this particular example could be of wider interest, but if anyone has another method to evaluate $f$ that would be acceptable too. I have tried inputting $f$ to various symbolic software (Mathematica, Maple, symja, SymPy) but none of those have been able to help. If you look at the revisions of this question, I originally included a section of other techniques I have tried, but I deleted it because this post is already too long and was not generating any activity.
How I Obtained $I\left(x\right)$ Via Egorychev's Method
I now think the most suitable representation (among many) of a power-of-two Chebyshev polynomial is $T_{2^n}\left(x\right) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(-1\right)^k \left(2^n\right)^{2k} \frac{\left(\cos^{-1} x\right)^{2k}}{\left(2k\right)!}$, which follows from the cosine series and the binomial theorem. This representation of $T$ is amenable to Egorgychev's method because it does not put $2^n$ as an exponent and moreover $\frac{\left(\cos^{-1} x\right)^{2k}}{\left(2k\right)!} = \frac{1}{2 \pi \imath} \int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} \frac{e^{z \cos^{-1} x}}{z^{2k + 1}} dz$, which is said to be valid if the radius of the circle merely satisfies $0 < \rho < \infty$.
Thus, the substitution step of Egorychev's method is
$$f\left(x\right) = \frac{3}{7} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 8^{-n} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(-1\right)^k \left(2^n\right)^{2k} \frac{1}{2 \pi \imath} \int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} \frac{e^{z \cos^{-1} x}}{z^{2k + 1}} dz$$
Interchanging the summation and integration,
$$f\left(x\right) = \frac{3}{7} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{8^{-n}}{4\pi \imath} \int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} e^{z \cos^{-1} x} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^k \left(2^n\right)^{2k}}{z^{2k + 1}} dz$$
If $\rho = \left|z\right| > 2^n$, we get that
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\left(-1\right)^k \left(2^n\right)^{2k}}{z^{2k + 1}} = \frac{z}{4^n + z^2}$$
and after interchanging the integral and the sum over $n$, we get
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{8^{-n}}{4\pi \imath} \frac{z}{4^n + z^2} = \frac{7\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(\imath z\right)\right)-7\psi_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_{2}\left(-\imath z\right)\right)-4\imath z\left(4z^{2}-7\right)\ln2}{56\pi z^{4}\ln2}$$
Using residues,
$$\int_{\left|z\right| = \rho} \frac{-16\imath}{56\pi z} e^{z \cos^{-1} x} dz = \frac{4}{7}$$
regardless of $\rho$, so I just brought the $\frac{3}{7}$ inside the contour integral and simplified to obtain the expression for $I\left(x\right)$ above.
If I numerically integrate $I\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ with $\rho \approx 23$, I get the right answer of $\frac{27 + 16 \sqrt{2}}{64}$ to four decimal places, so this derivation is presumably correct.

I'm not sure if its useful, but Mathematica indicates $$\Gamma_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_2(i z)\right)-\Gamma_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\log_2(-i z)\right)=-\frac{i, \left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right){\infty}}{2 z} \left(\frac{1}{\left(i z;\frac{1}{2}\right){\infty}}+\frac{1}{\left(-i z;\frac{1}{2}\right){\infty}}\right)$$ where $(a;q){\infty}$ is the q-Pochhammer symbol.

I don't think this function is 'well-behaved'.
To simplify, I suggest looking at your function $f(x)$ without the lowest order contributions
$$
  S_1(x) := \sum_{n>=1} T_{2^n}(x)/8^n = \sum_{n>=1} 2^{-3n}\cos(2^n y) =: S_2(y)
$$
where $y=\arccos(x)$.
This function $S_1(x)$ will be even (symmetric under $x\to-x$) and thus saves you some trouble in calculation of special values, e.g., $S_1(0)=-3/28$, $S_1(1)=S_1(-1)=1/7$, $S_1(1/2)=S_1(-1/2)=-1/14$, $S(\pm 0.743879727755700..) = 0$.
It can be easily ploted in Mathematica, if you use $\cos$ and $\arccos$ and avoid the Chebyshev polynomials

This function is known as a Weierstrass function, e.g., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function.
As per results quoted in a 2003 paper titled 'WEIERSTRASS FUNCTIONS WITH RANDOM PHASES' by YANICK HEURTEAUX (see, e.g., https://typeset.io/pdf/weierstrass-functions-with-random-phases-4ln6nj3leh.pdf), we have a version of the function
$$
w(z) = \sum_{n>=0} b^{−n\alpha} \cos(2 \pi b^n z)
$$
with $b=2$ and $\alpha=3$ and the function is continuous and differentiable.
However, the second derivative of $S_2(y)$ has $\alpha =1$ and is continuous but not differentiable
$$
S''_2(y) = - \sum_{n>=1} 2^{-n}\cos(2^n y) 
$$
Put differently: the 3rd derivative and higher derivatives do not exist and this may make analysis difficult depending on the method applied, e.g., finding the roots...
BTW: From the definition, it can be shown that $S_1(x)$ satisfies this functional equation
$$8 S_1(x) = S_1(-1+2x^2)    - 1 + 2 x^2$$
as well as
$$ 8 S_1(+/- \sqrt{(x'+1)/2]} = S_1(x') + x'$$
I find it remarkable that such an innocuous functional equation can create such a 'mess'; I guess there is more than one post on this site for this type of 'scenario'...
BTW2: From the functional equation you can attempt a Taylor expansion around $x=1$ to find that the derivatives grow without bound -as observed above; that also keeps the Taylor expansion from converging - put differently, the range of validity of that expansion is $0$.
